# FETCH API returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api

I am using FETCH API to get a value stored in a json file. That value has to go into a variable.

The problem is - the variable ends up holding [object Object] as value.

```
var title = fetch('URL/out.json', {mode: 'cors'});
```

In the htaccess of the server hosting the json file, there is the line

```
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

The json is as follows

```
 {
   lollol
}
```

I think the json might be the culprit.

I cannot find the reason for [object Object] to be the variable value.

Can I use Fetch to get a hosted text file? I tried - couldn't get it work. - just thinking of an alternative.

Comment: Actually it should return `[object Promise]`, unless you are using a polyfill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `.then()` as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch#Example):

```
fetch('URL/out.json', {mode: 'cors'}).then(function(response) {
    return response.blob();
}).then(function(response) {
    // process response
});
```

Comment: My response is now [object Blob].

Comment: @CodyRaspien You assing title inside second `then()`, not just full response?

Comment: var title = fetch('URL/out.json', {mode: 'cors'}).then(function(response) {
    return response.blob();
}).then(function(response) {
response.toString;
});

Still getting [object blob]

Comment: @CodyRaspien Try `var title;` `[...].then(function(response) { title = response.toString; });`

Comment: title now contains "undefined".

Answer (score 3):

you need to stringify the object to convert it into JSON string.

try `JSON.stringify(theObject)`

Comment: stringify outputs {"type":"text/html","size":4}

Answer (score 1):

fetch API is very promise-oriented
fetch returns a promise with a response object as a param
you then need to call a method on the response to give you another promise with the result

heres an example i did.  On the first .then()  i called .json on the response so can i get my results on the next .then()

```
export function newVideoAsync(videoData, url) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(videoData)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsonData => {
      dispatch(videoSuccess(jsonData))
      console.log(jsonData);
      // find video id to redirect to that video
      // client side redirect to '/video/:id'
      browserHistory.push('/')
    })
    .catch(err => dispatch(videoError(err.message)));
  };
};
```

https://davidwalsh.name/fetch

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
var myRequest = new Request('URL');
var title;
fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
    return response.text().then(function(text) {
        title= text; 
        alert (title);
    });
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure that would throw a `ReferenceError` since `response` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still experiencing this issue while following correct `fetch` syntax, please try to do these next steps (before pulling your hair out :)):

1. clean cache from your project
2. remove and reinstall external libs/modules
3. restart your project